# Reinstall Ubuntu on non-booting partition keeping the files

Tags: reinstall

I have a corrupted internal ssd with Ubuntu installed that does not boot anymore. However using a USB stick booting device I manged to:

- uncrypt the disk using `Disks` application using my encryption password. After that another volume appear: clicking on the Play-like button, it mounts;
- After that I navigate through the volume to `home/my_usr` and found the file `Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop`
- I installed `ecryptfs-utils` with:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository universe
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install ecryptfs-utils
  ```
- I navigate to the folder `media/ubuntu/long_disk_string/home`
- I did `ecryptfs-recover-private .ecryptfs/my_usr/.Private` and the old disk was mount in a `/tmp/` folder.

Since here I can see all my files are ok, is there a way to repair/reinstall Ubuntu keeping the old/existing uncorrupted data without formatting the partition?

Comment: Before doing anything Else, back up all your data. Anyone using encryption must have good backups as often you cannot open encrypted partition as you have been able to do and then no way to recover data. Often corruption is caused by abnormal shutdown. And then fsck will fix issue. This user ran fsck, but that cause loss of password, so that must have been where corruption was? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2375964

Comment: Already colied all the home folder: it literally took days. I described the procedure first of all to give more info for my problem and then to help people who might want to recover the data as I did